# Issue building JAR out of Spring app that can be deployed on Azure

Tags: java, spring, azure, gradle, jar

I have a Spring Boot REST app that is working locally, and I want to deploy it to Microsoft Azure. To do so, I need to create an executable jar. I am using the Spring Tool Suite (Eclipse). When I export, I am choosing the option "Extract required libraries into generated JAR" Whenever I run the JAR in cmd, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes 
found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make 
sure that file is correct.
```

If I choose the option "Package required libraries into generated JAR," I get the following error (after a bit of a wait):

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL [rsrc:hello/] cannot be resolved to 
 absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: 
 rsrc:hello/
 at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:215) ~
 [jar:rsrc:spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
```

When I choose to copy required libraries into a subfolder next to the JAR file, the JAR runs fine locally but the web app will not repond when the JAR and lib file are hosted on Azure (placed in my wwwroot directory with a web.config file that points to the jar).

My question: Which of these three do I need to choose, and how do I get this JAR running on Azure? I feel like this is just a problem with my build.gradle, which you can see here:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

springBoot {
    mainClass = "src.main.java.hello.Application"
    executable = true
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-rest-service'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
     compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
     compile('org.springframework:spring-jdbc')
}
```

I would really appreciate any help, as I have been unable to find an answer elsewhere.